# TFS - Make a child branch the main branch and abandon original parent

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, merge

Somehow, my Visual Studio project got very much messed up. The source code was good, but things were messed up in some of the configuration files. After hours of fighting with it, I found an earlier changeset (changeset 20) that compiled and ran fine, albeit without the latest changes (I was up to changeset 25 by now).

I then performed the following steps:

1. I retrieved a copy of changeset 20 into a new temporary workspace.
2. I used WinMerge to manually merge the latest source code changes into the changeset 20 code that was in my temp workspace.
3. I branched my main branch (called MainBranch) in TFS to a new branch called TempBranch.
4. I manually copied my merged files (from step 2) from the temp workspace into the main workspace for TempBranch.
5. I checked the merged code into TempBranch.

My Heirarchy looks like this now:

[image: TFS Heirarchy]

So, now, TempBranch has all the latest "good" code, and none of the corrupt configuration files. MainBranch has the bad configuration files.

So now that TempBranch is exactly how I want it, and it's what I want to base all further development on, what should I do at this point, so that MainBranch is basically identical to TempBranch?

I'm worried that if I try to merge the branches, it will try to merge the bad config files in MainBranch with the good ones in TempBranch. I want to make sure that for all differences in the two branches, the TempBranch version "wins".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can try to merge **from TempBranch to MainBranch**, and take source branch if there are conflicts.
2. If the history is not important in MainBranch, you can reparent the TempBranch, and choose No parent. Then there is no hierarchy between TempBranch and MainBranch, you can work on TempBranch.

[image]

Comment: If I do #1, what constitutes a conflict? If different changes were made in a particular file in each branch, I don't want it to combine the two files, even if different lines were modified. I want the TempBranch version to be the one to take no matter what.

Comment: How about option2? You can reparent TempBranch as No parent, then only work in TempBranch.

Comment: Thanks. I did Option 2. I reparented TempBranch as No Parent, then renamed MainBranch to "OldAbandonedBranch", then renamed TempBranch to "MainBranch".